# Use ng-model to add class to all previous childrens Angular JS

Tags: json, angularjs, variables, angularjs-scope

Here is my html code:

```
  <div ng-repeat="(key, a) in items" data-id="{{ Id }}" class="item" id="{{Key}}" ng-click="item($event, key)">
            <div class="bubble></div>
            <p>
                <span> {{ description }}</span>
            </p>
  </div>
```

This is the list of items. When we click on the item in the list - all previous elements are set as active (add class).
Here is how it's done:

```
  $scope.item = function(event, key) {
    var current;
    if ( $(event.target).hasClass('bubble')){
        current =   $(event.target).closest('#'+ Key);
        changeItem(current);
    }
    function changeItem(current){
        $(current).addClass('active');
        $(current).prevAll().addClass('active');
        $(current).nextAll().removeClass('active');
    }
};
```

Is it possible to use ng-model or something else to set the active value by default form json file? Mean, in json  - we have item 3 - marked as active, so how could I add this value to the  $scope.item as current? or probably use ng-model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried it, but something like this should work.Assuming that the class has to be applied to `ng-repeat` div. Change your ng-repeat div to:

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key, a) in items" data-id="{{ Id }}" class="item" id="{{Key}}" ng-click="markSelected($index)" ng-class="{'active':selectedIndex<$index}">
  </div>
```

The `ng-click` call a method `markSelected($index)` on the controller that sets the currently selected item index. The `ng-class` uses the current index (`$index`) and the `selectedIndex` to determine what class to apply.

The final task is to implement the function which looks like:

```
$scope.markSelected=function(index) {
   $scope.selectedIndex=index;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should stop using jquery and start to think in a more angular way.

There is a directive `ng-class` that is used to add or remove classes

You can find more information here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, a) in items" data-id="{{ Id }}" class="item" id="{{Key}}" ng-click="item(key)">
        <div ng-class="{active : a.active, inactive : a.inactive}"></div>
        <p>
            <span> {{ description }}</span>
        </p>
</div>

$scope.item = function(key){
    $scope.items[key].active = true;
    $scope.items[key].inactive = false;
}
```